# Block network browsing in ms 2003 and ms2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I have lan environment like this 17 pc client os ms xp sp3 and server 2003, I have to disable \browsing through GPO. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a single subnet, you can not set a default gateway on the NICs of the client machines, but if you have more than one subnet, this will break routing. Not to mention that it's dirty.

GPO isn't the tool to do this with. You need to either disable HTTP/HTTPS outbound on your firewall or set up a proxy that will do the same thing.